# PHP Get input name

Tags: php, forms, input, get

Upon posting a form using `_GET` I would like to get the input name

See below part of url upon submit

`.php?14=0&15=0&16=0&17=0&18=0&19=0`

I know how to get the variable E.G:

```
$14=$_GET["14"];
```

Which is `0`

However is it possible to do this and get the input name (eg 14) and then turn these into variables? (To save the input name to the DB)

Comment: What do you want to insert in database? `14,15,16`? each in individual row?

Comment: Yes, I have a column called question name and another called answer, so column name needs to be 14 and answer needs to be 0 if that makes sense?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Solution using single loop (Update):**

If you're just using question/answer single time you can do it in single loop like this,

```
<?php

foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    $question = $key;
    $answer = $value;

    // Save question and answer accordingly.
}
```

If you will be using question answer to perform other things, use the following method.

---

You can get all the **keys**  using [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), where **$_GET** is an array.

Use it like this,

```
<?php
     $keys=array_keys($_GET);
     print_r($keys); // this will print all the keys
     foreach($keys as $key) {
         // access each key here with $key
     }
```

**Update:**

You can make a pair of question,answer array and put it in the main array to insert it in the database like this,

```
<?php
         $mainArray=array();
         $keys=array_keys($_GET);
         foreach($keys as $key) {
             // access each key here with $key
             $questionAnswerArray=array();
             $questionAnswerArray["question"]=$key;
             $questionAnswerArray["answer"]=$_GET[$key];
             $mainArray[]=$questionAnswerArray;
         }

         // Now traverse this array to insert the data in database.
         foreach($mainArray as $questionanswer) {
              echo $questionanswer["question"]; //prints the question
              echo $questionanswer["answer"]; // prints the answer.
         }
```

Comment: Thanks, see updated question, im looking to turn these into variables so I can add them to a DB

Comment: Thanks this is showing as `Array ( [0] => 14 [1] => 15 [2] => 16 [3] => 17 [4] => 18 [5] => 19 ) 140150160170180190` how would I add these to my DB?

Comment: You can use `$questionanswer["question"]` to add in in question's column and `$questionanswer["answer"]` to add in answer's column.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the `$_GET` parameters, you can do:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    echo "Key is $key and value is $value<br>";
}
```

This will output each key (14, 15, 16 etc) and value (0, 0, 0 etc).

---

To bind a variable name with a variable string, look at [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

As a result, you will have the following variables with the following values:

```
$14 = 0;
$15 = 0;
$16 = 0;
// etc...
```

---

Alternatively (as you don't necessarily know what the key/value pairs would be), you could create an empty array and add these keys and values to it:

```
foreach($_GET as $k => $v){
    $arr[$k] = $v;
}
```

The resulting array will be:

```
$arr[14] = 0;
$arr[15] = 0;
$arr[16] = 0;
// etc...
```

Comment: How can I turn these into variables? (To save the input name to the DB)